# XPath Parsing in JRuby

Tags: arrays, ruby, xml, xpath, jruby

This is my line of code in JRuby when

```
XPath.match(@xmlDoc, "//services/service[./serviceType = 'ADDRESSBOOK']/@data-uri").value
```

When I run this I get this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `value' for #<Array:0x6b39d609>
```

Any idea how can I do get as array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse an array and print value of each element

```
xpath_array = XPath.match(@xmlDoc, "//services/service[./serviceType = 'ADDRESSBOOK']/@data-uri")
    xpath_array.each do |element|
    puts element.value
end
```

Comment: great, it worked. could you please explain the code what actually it did?

Comment: 1. You have requested DOM for array of elements matching XPath
2. You iterate through array using .each method and place each iterated element to 'element' variable
3. You print inner value of an element with 'puts' command.

I suggest you to read a book regarding ruby because this question was so simple...